# Retornar média de custo entre produtos parcialmente iguais

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-select

Conforme exemplifico no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65e08/2), preciso que dadas as tabelas, os dados sejam retornados da seguinte forma:

```
nome     | descricao| tipo    | custo|    ult_lancamento      | entradas | saidas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProdutoA | ProdutoA | ACABADO | 0.91 | May,12 2017 15:39:00   |   220    | 90
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProdutoB | ProdutoB | PRIMA   | 1.25 | March,24 2017 07:40:00 |   50     | (null)
```

Ou seja, produtos que tenham o mesmo nome e a mesma descrição serão retornados como um produto contendo uma média do custo, a soma de suas entradas e de suas saidas e a última data de lançamento. No SQL Fiddle, contém o que consegui fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue código para sua necessidade:

```
Select
p.nome,
p.tipo,
avg(p.custo) as custo_medio,
sum(coalesce(le.quantidade,0)) as entradas,
sum(coalesce(ls.quantidade,0)) as saidas,
(select MAX(data_lancamento) from lancamentos where id_produto=p.id) as ultimo_lancamento
from produtos p
left outer join lancamentos le on le.id_produto = p.id and le.operacao = 'ENTRADA'
left outer join lancamentos ls on ls.id_produto = p.id and ls.operacao = 'SAIDA'
where exists (select * from lancamentos where id_produto = p.id)
group by p.nome,p.tipo
```

Algumas Observações:

1-Não entendi o porque de dois produtos com o mesmo nome, isso pode te trazer problemas, não faça assim.

2-Utilize a tabela de lançamentos para armazenar o preço de custo, dessa forma você terá todo o histórico de custo do produto, na respectiva data do seu lançamento. Mesma situação para preço de venda.

3-Não utilize 'ENTRADA' e 'SAIDA' para diferenciar os registros da movimentação, quando for uma saída, utilize valores negativos, e entrada, positivos, para extrair o saldo do produto, basta executar o 'Sum', e se ainda assim for necessário diferenciar os registros, utilize números, ex: 0-Entrada / 1-Saidas

Comment: a sua resposta retornou todos os produtos. Inclusive os que não tinham lançamentos. Além disso, a soma das saídas não foi feita, perceba que o resultado foi null. Quanto a suas observações, eu estou cadastrando produtos que têm o mesmo nome e descrição pois há a possibilidade de um mesmo produto ser comprado de fornecedores diferentes e com preços diferentes. Quanto as outras duas dicas, eu gostei.

Comment: sobre a primeira observação, a segunda resolve o problema de fornecedores  e preços diferentes, armazene o fornecedor também na tabela de movimentação se for o caso, aí você fica com o banco normalizado, terá um histórico de compras, preços e fornecedores para cada produto. Sobre sair os produtos que não tiveram movimentação, não havia nada especificando que não deveriam sair, então optei pelo left outer join, basta trocar essa clausula por inner join. =]

Comment: voltei ao Fiddle para verficar, somente um produto teve 1 saída, logo os outros sairiam como null mesmo

Comment: @Ronvann mudei para inner join, mas nada foi retornado. No Fiddle o ProdutoA teve uma saída, mas na soma final (feito com left outer join) saiu como null. Quanto a suas dicas, eu manteria o preço e o fornecedor em Lançamentos e retiraria do produto, certo?

Comment: tentei abrir o Fiddle para mexer no código e dá erro de sincronização =/. E sim, da mesma forma que no lançamento você pode ter um cliente para manter o histórico de compras do cliente (obs. eu faço cliente e fornecedores na mesma tabela, fica apenas uma FK na tabela de lançamentos)

Comment: Realmente tá dando erro. Se importa de me explicar melhor essa ideia dos campos pelo chat do hangouts? Pelo menos a gente não enche o post aqui e quando resolvermos a query do sql postamos a resposta.

Comment: nunca usei o hangouts, só me falar como =] hehe, pesquisa pelo meu nome lá que deve aparecer

Comment: É o bate-papo do gmail. Te enviei o convite